# How to create dynamic table headers from JSON in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON array of objects, I want to create a dynamic table columns/headers based on it in React.

The data:

```
example = [
  {
    id: 0,
    city: 'New York',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    city: 'Paris',
  },
]
```

I want to iterate through the array, get the key and add extra fields. 
So far I have:

```
columns() {
    return Object.keys(Example[0]).map((key) => {
      return {
        cityName: key,
        capital: false,
      };
    });
  }
```

I get the keys, but they are unordered (random) and the extra field is added to **all** the objects. I want to get each key to use it as table header (column name) and be able to change `capital` for each object.
How can I do that in React?

Comment: are you sure about `Example[0]).map((key)...` must be with small `e`?

Comment: No this was a mistake when I wrote the question, it's correct in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.map for this.

```
example = [
  {
    id: 0,
    city: 'New York',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    city: 'Paris',
  },
];
example.map((obj) => {
  return {
   CITY : obj.city,
   ID : obj.id
   // Do whatever with the objects
 }
})
```

Comment: That returns the field, e.g. 'New York', I want to get the key; city. 
I want to use the key as table header.

Comment: If you want to get the key, now run a loop on objects inside map. i.e. Object.keys on each object and you can easily get the key.

Comment: you mean a new map inside map? I'm not sure if that's the best way, or even if it works.

Comment: No, object.keys...loop through the obj

Comment: example.map((obj) => {
 for(var k in obj) {
  console.log(k) // do something with the keys
 };
})

Answer (score 0):

```
arr => arr && arr[0] ? object.keys(arr[0]) : [];
```

make sure all items in array have same keys